# How can I do an action when login session timed out in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, session, timeout

The problem is that I need to do an action the moment a session expires, regardless of whether the browser is open or not.

I have a project in Laravel and it is registered when the user is online or offline, when he logs into the system, it registers in the database 1 for the user who is online, and when he leaves, it registers 0. I want it to register 0 when the session expired without the user needing to refresh the screen. Even if the user closes the browser without logging out, the system will register that the user is offline when the session expires.

My English is not good and this is my first question here on the platform.
Thank you anyway!

**------------------------------------------------**

**My Solution**

I did it this way:

I noticed that Laravel's session files store the user's record ID when they log in to the system. The file, when the user is offline, looks something like this:

```
a:2:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"qA6WE6udLLaj1kBIcvvnJxasLiCRijRIV7WmqeyP";s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}}
```

And when the user is logged in, it looks like this:

```
a:4:{s:6:"_token";s:40:"Fee9jVGzN1P50d5aXUgY80EWcoop5azNu44qbsi9";s:9:"_previous";a:1:{s:3:"url";s:43:"http://laravel-site.com/home";}s:6:"_flash";a:2:{s:3:"old";a:0:{}s:3:"new";a:0:{}}s:50:"login_web_59ba36addc2b2f9401580f014c7f58ea4e30989d";i:1;}
```

With this information, I came up with some solutions to address certain scenarios.

***1st Scenario:***

If the user is logged in but inactive (not performing any actions in the system) for 15 minutes, they are redirected to a route that initiates logout and then sent to the login screen. I accomplished this with JavaScript. I added the following code to the blade template that serves as the base for all screens.

```
    ...
    <body>
    ...

      <form id="logoutForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}">
            @csrf <!-- Token CSRF -->
      </form>

    ...
    </body>
    ...

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // Script to log out the inactive user and redirect to the Login screen

        // Set the inactivity timeout in milliseconds (e.g., 5 minutes)
        var inactivityTimeout = 15 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes in milliseconds

        // Variable to store the last user interaction time
        var lastInteractionTime = new Date().getTime();

        // Function to check inactivity and log out the user if necessary
        function checkInactivity() {
            var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
            var elapsedTime = currentTime - lastInteractionTime;

            if (elapsedTime >= inactivityTimeout) {
                // Perform logout
                $('#logoutForm').submit();
            }
        }

        // Function to update the last user interaction time
        function updateLastInteractionTime() {
            lastInteractionTime = new Date().getTime();
        }

        // Add event listeners to detect user interactions
        $(document).on('mousemove keydown click', updateLastInteractionTime);

        // Check inactivity every second
        setInterval(checkInactivity, 1000);

    </script>
```

***2nd Scenario:***

If the user was logged in and simply closed the browser without logging out, their session remains active for 1 hour as defined in the session's lifetime configuration in the config/session.php file:

**config/session.php**

```
'lifetime' => env('SESSION_LIFETIME', 60),

'expire_on_close' => false,
```

**.env**

```
SESSION_LIFETIME=60
```

To terminate this session, I created a new Laravel command using the command:

php artisan make:command UserSessionCleanup

Inside the newly generated file **/app/Console/Commands/UserSessionCleanup.php**, I created the script that the command will execute:

```php
    <?php

    namespace App\Console\Commands;

    use App\Models\LogAccessManager;
    use App\Models\Notification;
    use App\Models\User;
    use App\Models\UserNotification;
    use Illuminate\Console\Command;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

    class UserSessionCleanup extends Command
    {
        /**
         * The name and signature of the console command.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $signature = 'UserSessionCleanup';

        /**
         * The console command description.
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $description = "The UserSessionCleanup script manages user sessions, updating users' online status to offline, and removing expired sessions.";

        /**
         * Execute the console command.
         *
         * @return int
         */
        public function handle()
        {
            $sessionPath = storage_path('framework/sessions');
            $allSessions = [];

            if (is_dir($sessionPath)) {
                $sessionFiles = scandir($sessionPath);

                // Step 1: Collect information from all sessions
                foreach ($sessionFiles as $file) {
                    if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..') {
                        $filePath = $sessionPath . '/' . $file;
                        $fileContent = file_get_contents($filePath);

                        $pattern = '/"login_web_[a-f0-9]+";i:(\d+)/';
                        preg_match($pattern, $fileContent, $matches);

                        if (!empty($matches)) {
                            $userId = $matches[1];
                            $creationTime = filectime($filePath);
                            $formattedTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $creationTime);

                            $allSessions[] = [
                                'user_id' => $userId,
                                'date_file' => $formattedTime,
                                'file_name' => $file,
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }

                // Step 2: Filter latest sessions for each user_id
                $latestSessions = [];
                foreach ($allSessions as $session) {
                    $userId = $session['user_id'];
                    if (!isset($latestSessions[$userId]) || $session['date_file'] > $latestSessions[$userId]['date_file']) {
                        $latestSessions[$userId] = $session;
                    }
                }

                // Step 3: Filter sessions with files created more than a minute ago
                $filteredSessions = [];
                foreach ($latestSessions as $session) {
                    $creationTimestamp = strtotime($session['date_file']);
                    $currentTimestamp = time();
                    $timeDifference = $currentTimestamp - $creationTimestamp;

                    if ($timeDifference > (15 * 60)) {  // 15 minutes in seconds
                        $filteredSessions[] = $session;
                    }
                }

                $i = 0;

                if (!empty($filteredSessions)) {
                    // Step 4: Update status_online in the users' table
                    $userIdsToUpdate = array_column($filteredSessions, 'user_id');

                    if (Schema::hasTable('users')) {
                        foreach ($userIdsToUpdate as $userId) {

                            $userOnline = User::find($userId);
                            $userOnline->status_online = 0;
                            $userOnline->save();

                            $i++;
                        }
                    } else {
                        echo "The users' table does not exist.\n";
                    }

                    // Step 5: Remove files of filtered sessions
                    foreach ($filteredSessions as $session) {
                        $filePath = $sessionPath . '/' . $session['file_name'];
                        if (file_exists($filePath)) {
                            unlink($filePath);
                        }
                    }
                }

                echo "Number of expired sessions: $i\n";

            } else {
                echo "The sessions directory does not exist.\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

This script checks for logged-in user sessions that haven't been updated for more than 15 minutes. If such sessions are found, it records information in the database about each user being offline and removes the session file to prevent the possibility of the user returning with the session still active.

Then I configured the command to run every 17 minutes, as I thought it would be a suitable interval for checking sessions inactive for over 15 minutes. This configuration is in the **/app/Console/Kernel.php** file:

```
    /**
     * Define the application's command schedule.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Console\Scheduling\Schedule  $schedule
     * @return void
     */
    protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        ...

        $schedule->command('UserSessionCleanup')->cron('*/17 * * * *');
        // ->appendOutputTo('/app/storage/logs/scheduler.log');
         
        ...   
    }
```

***3rd Scenario:***

If the user is logged in and actively interacting with the system by clicking around or moving the mouse, they won't be disconnected.

I chose 15 minutes to meet the requirements of PCI DSS 12.3.8. You can find more information about it in the following link:

https://www.pcidssguide.com/pci-dss-session-timeout-requirements/

This is the approach I came up with. It's not flawless, but it helps me achieve the necessary actions.

Thank you very much, everyone!

Comment: You could try registering a `Listener` for the `Illuminate\Auth\Events\Logout` event.

Comment: All i can think of is ping pong method which might not be that good, you will perform a request to the server every few minutes which saves the request time and session state and server will run command to disable the session (0) after the set time has passed after the last request from the front end.This will open another whole can of worms like what if user is in multiple devices etc. So your question should be how the chats shows the online status of the user. Try to research that and see if the tech stack used on it (sockets) feasible for you.

Comment: This is like a WebSocket requirement

Answer (score 1):

liquid207 thanks for replying! I am using `file` as session driver

I kept doing some testing and researching further and found this link which discusses this very issue:

[Laravel session timeout, extra logout code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031341/laravel-session-timeout-extra-logout-code)

In this case, a middleware is used, but if the user closes the browser without exiting, even with the browser closed, will the middleware work?

Comment: No, middleware just work when request is coming.
You can change `DatabaseSessionHandler` in my reply to  `FileSessionHandler`

Answer (score 0):

Method `SessionHandlerInterface::gc()` will be invoke when session expires. You can override this method according to the following steps:

I suppose that you use `database` as session driver.

1. Create a class extend `DatabaseSessionHandler`, override `gc`
2. Create a class extend `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager`, override `createDatabaseDriver` to return class defined in step 1
3. Register class defined in step 2, like

   ```
      $this->app->singleton('session', function (Application $app) {
           return new CustomSessionManager($app);
       });
   ```